# Definition of Singular Integrals Operators

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, singular-integrals

Consider an integrable function $\Omega$ on $S^{n-1}$ with mean value zero, ie $\int_{S^{n-1}}\Omega =0$, and define the tempered distribution

$$\langle W_\Omega, \phi \rangle = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{|x|\geq \varepsilon}\frac{\Omega(x/|x|)}{|x|^n} \phi(x) dx, \;\;\; \forall \phi \in \mathcal{S}{(\mathbb{R}^n)} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(*)$$

The singular integral operator $T_\Omega$ is defined to be the convolution with $W_\Omega$, ie
$$T_\Omega \phi = \phi \ast W_\Omega, \;\;\; \forall \phi \in \mathcal{S}{(\mathbb{R}^n)}. $$

It was not a problem for me to verify that $W_\Omega$ is in fact a tempered distribution and so is well defined the singular integral oepator $T_\Omega$. My problem here is about the existence of the limit above. Once proved that $W_\Omega$ is a tempered distribution, is it immediate that the limit exists or I have to show that the limit exists by the Dominated Convergence Theorem?

**Attempt:** Rewrite  the integral
$$\int_{|x|\geq \varepsilon}\frac{\Omega(x/|x|)}{|x|^n} \phi(x) dx = \int_{|x|\geq \varepsilon}\frac{\Omega(x/|x|)}{|x|^n} (\phi(x) - \phi(0)) dx.$$
That's possible, because the fact that $\Omega$ has mean value zero implies that $\frac{\Omega(x/|x|)}{|x|^n} \phi(x)$ also has mean value zero. So it is suffices to show that exists the limit
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{|x|\geq \varepsilon}\frac{\Omega(x/|x|)}{|x|^n}
( \phi(x) - \phi(0)) dx \;\;\;\;\;\;\; (**)$$

By the Mean Value Theorem for $\phi$
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{\Omega(x/|x|)}{|x|^n} ( \phi(x) - \phi(0)) \right|
& = \left|\frac{\Omega(x/|x|)}{|x|^n} \nabla\phi(\xi)\cdot x \right|\\
& \leq \frac{|\Omega(x/|x|)|}{|x|^{n-1}} \|\nabla\phi\|_{L^\infty}.
\end{align*}
By polar coordinates and using the fact that $\Omega \in L^1(S^{n-1})$, its not difficult to show that the function on the right-hand of the inequality is integrable. So by the Dominated Convergence Theorem, the limit $(**)$ exists. So its proved that $(*)$ also exists.